# pixel art tree using 3/4 perspective

Tags: sprites, tiles, rpg, pixel-art

Is there a correct way to calculate the exact proportions for drawing a tree sprite for an RPG. These are the types of trees I am aiming to create(sorry for the huge picture, I dont how to scale it down):

[image]
The tutorial here, http://cyangmou.deviantart.com/art/Pixel-Art-Tutorial-3-The-perfect-crate-311089437, perfectly describes how to create an object using the 3/4 perspective but when I apply this method when drawing a tree it doesn't quite work. Is there a different method that I could use for creating non-rectangle shaped objects like a tree or other strangely shaped objects, or am I going about it wrong?

Thank you in advance :D.

Comment: What do you mean by *"it doesn't quite work"*? What is the problem? (Also that tutorial is a bit long - you should probably point out what exactly you tried)